# Find the limit of $a^n/b_n$, where $b_n=\prod\limits_{i=1}^n(1+a^i)$, for $a\ne-1$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, products

> Find the limit of $$a_n=\frac{a^n}{\prod_{i=1}^n(1+a^i)}$$
>   where $a \ne -1$.

**What I've got so far:**

$$a_n=\frac{1}{\prod_{i=1}^{n-1}(1+a^i)}-\frac{1}{\prod_{i=1}^n(1+a^i)}$$

Now, I can see $a_n\to 0$ since the products in the denominators are divergent. 
I guess what I'm left with is proving that the products are divergent which I don't know how to do.

Comment: You might want to treat separately the cases $|a|<1$ and $|a|>1$ since the convergence $a_n\to0$ is driven by $a^n$ in the numerator in the former case and by the product in the denominator in the latter case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let 
$$F_n(a):=\frac{a^n}{\prod_{i=1}^n(1+a^i)}.$$
Note that if $0<|a|<1 $ then 
$$0<|F_n(a)|\leq \frac{|a|^n}{\prod_{i=1}^n(1-|a|^i)}
\leq \frac{|a|^n}{1-\sum_{i=1}^n|a|^i}
=|a|^n\left(1-\frac{|a|(1-|a|^{n+1})}{1-|a|}\right)^{-1}\to 0$$
as $n$ goes to infinity.
For $a=1$,
$$0<F_n(1)=\frac{1}{2^n}\to 0.$$
Moreover
$$F_n(1/a)=\frac{(1/a)^n}{\prod_{i=1}^n(1+(1/a)^i)}=
\frac{a^{-n}\cdot a^{\sum_{i=1}^n i}}{\prod_{i=1}^n(a^i+1)}=
F_n(a)\cdot a^{\frac{n^2-3n}{2}}.$$
Hence, if  $|a|>1$, then $0<|1/a|<1$ and for $n\to+\infty$, $|a|^{\frac{n^2-3n}{2}}\to +\infty$, and 
$$|F_n(a)|=\frac{|F_n(1/a)|}{|a|^{\frac{n^2-3n}{2}}}\to 0.$$